# How can I remove the bullet points that appear in the navigation menu only in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, internet-explorer-8, bulletedlist

I have an issue with internet explorer. I have been building a menu with CSS and html and everything works just fine in the other web browsers, but when it comes to Internet Explorer, the bullet points appear when you hover over the menu item for a moment. They have all been hidden with CSS and I've tried adding the list-style: none element wherever I can but nothing is working. Any ideas?!

Website: http://www.carrallinson.com

I can add more information on the CSS but it's all pretty complex. As a snippet:

```
.main-navigation ul ul li {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover,
.main-navigation ul ul li.focus {
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 1.0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

So that is what is confusing. It's all been listed as "none" yet somehow appears?!

Comment: Which IE version are you using?

Comment: @Highdef tags say IE8

Comment: In IE11 the bullet points do not appear for me on hover.

Comment: Yeah, its IE8 @sol

Comment: Can be seen on Edge too

Comment: Try removing `list-style: none;` from `.main-navigation ul ul li:hover`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of this for the older IE versions. Not sure if it would work for IE8 as list-style-type:none works well for IE11.

**Reference:** https://github.com/tjvantoll/jquery-ui/commit/6acd1c8640b271db7df03f1457a817d5d6a1f29d

```css
li {
  list-style-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

**Another alternative is to use:**

```
li {
list-style-position: outside;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style-position: outside;
  overflow: hidden;
}

Position the bullet outside of the list and hide the overflow.
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```